# How to fetch change of Facebook account in Facebook app in iOS SDK while logging in and authorize again?

Tags: ios, facebook

Here is the scenario:

I open my iOS app, click Login with Facebook, it opens up my Facebook app, authorizes me and redirects me to my iOS app and I am logged in. Next, I close my iOS app. Go back to Facebook app, logout and login with a different account. Now, I open my iOS app and it logs in using cached accessToken of the previous Facebook account (that now I logged out of).

What I want to do is to verify, if the cached accessToken is valid and related to the account currently logged in my Facebook app on the iOS device? If not, then I could clear session information and ask my iOS app user to authorize again?

Answer (score 0):

Once a user is looged in using FB SDK, it will remain logged in unless you manually use `FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation]`

You have to call before to use another FB Login.

Comment: So, there is no other way to check what account is logged in the Facebook app? Using `FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation` will not login automatically, if the previous accessToken is the same as the one for the profile currently logged in the Facebook app. Any other solutions?